# How to I set Word in Office 365 to not automatically create an anchored frame around tables or table rows?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, table-styles

How do I set Word (Office 365 Business) to *not* automatically *create* an anchored frame around every table (or table row) when I select or edit content in the table or row? This “anchored frame” issue appeared in September 2019 (now using build 1908).

Maybe there’s a subtle automation that I am missing. It is so frequent that I found “Remove Frame” and added it to my shortcut menu.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs after Office 365 is updated to version 1908. I suggest you can try update operating system to the latest  version at first.

And I also use the Office 365 version 1908, but I don't have that problem.

Maybe you can try open Word in safe mode to to rule out the effects of the plugin. Refer to   [Open Office apps in safe mode on a Windows PC](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)

Or try repairing Office application.

If none of the above helps, maybe you should wait for the next version of Office 365...